# Catching garbage collections from within an Android app?

Tags: java, android

I'm designing an Android app which loads lots of small (say 128x128px@24-bit) PNG images as Bitmaps to be drawn on a View. There's a lot of them - combined they form a 3000x3000px map!

The map only loads the Bitmaps from the .png files when you first look at their section of the map, and they need to be drawn. Until then, they are not loaded.

I want to be able to unload (Bitmap.recycle()) the images when they've been off-screen for a certain period of time, otherwise the user scrolling around the map is going to quickly fill up the application heap.

Are there any ways of catching when the GC wants to run in the class which encapsulates the Bitmap images, so I can manually unload the Bitmaps which haven't been onscreen over a threshold time? Obviously the Dalvik GC won't unload the images itself as they always have live references.

(PS: I'm not using the Google Maps APIs as a challenge to myself - but it would be interesting to see how they handle the drawing of, say, satellite imagery... do they do what I do and dynamically load/unload image sections from file?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than unloading the images based on *time*, why not do it based on *distance*?  The farther a tile is outside the visible boundaries, the less likely it is to be needed soon, assuming that all movement is by scrolling.  You can choose a threshold — say, four tiles beyond the visible area — and unload any images that are outside that boundary.

As you scroll around, you'll be able to unload one row or column of tiles at the same time you need to load another, so your total memory usage remains constant.

Comment: In addition to this I'd like to recommend to move loading-unloading image into separate thread. I've impleemented such behavior for TV guide (scrolling through thousands of TV show previews) and achieved big improvement in application speed.

Comment: I think this is what Google Maps does, btw.

Comment: I think that Google Maps uses huge amount of native code, so all image handling is putted to "low-level" here.

Comment: Distance does sound better actually, and that also solves the problem of when to check whether it should be unloaded or not. I didn't want to be polling every so often as that would be wasting cycles on the phone... but having it check on a touch/drag event would be better yes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise relying on the garbage collector since this could be called erratically. It's probably better to have code that runs in your app which occasionally checks images and unloads if necessary.